# Python - UDP socket bind() to the correct address

Tags: python, sockets, udp, bind

I can't understand why if I create a socket in this way

```
from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(("192.168.1.10",26000))
print s.recvfrom(4096)[0]
```

and I try to send to it a broadcast packet like this

```
from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.sendto("hey!", ("<broadcast>", 26000))
```

it doesn't work (it hangs on the recvfrom()) but if I try to bind it to "0.0.0.0" it receives the packet correctly.

I know that 0.0.0.0 means that every address on every interface will be listening on that port, but why binding directly to an address makes it don't receive the packet?

**Operating system: OSX 10.9.2, Python version: 2.7.6**

Even if I'm not running Linux, I tried binding the socket to the subnet broadcast address anyway, same results.

Comment: Which operating system do you use? Have you tried something like wireshark to have a look at which messages are sent over the interfaces when you broadcast?

Comment: What OS? If it's Linux it seems that it's not possible for non-root https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/576 You need to use 0.0.0.0 or just a separate socket

Comment: You may try to bind to the subnet broadcast address (for example 192.168.1.255, depending on your settings) as it's said here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666789/receiving-udp-broadcast-packets-on-linux

Comment: The `socket()` function accepts three arguments and I don't think the third one is optional in any case.

Comment: And be careful about the port numbers. They should always be enclosed in `htons()` so that you see the actual port number in the code and not a number with reversed byte order.

Comment: @Pavel: As described here, the socket function requires two arguments. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#creating-a-socket

Comment: @Kava: Wrong. The HOWTO is indeed not entirely correct here. The function accepts three arguments just as the POSIX C function does. Python allows all of them to be omitted (which I didn't realize at first).

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html – although I wouldn't agree that leaving out the protocol is a good idea for AF_INET/AF_INET6.

Answer (score 4):

If the operating system is Linux then try to bind socket to the subnet broadcast address.
For example, if your `ifconfig` settings are `inet addr:192.168.0.62  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0`then bind your receiver socket to `192.168.0.255`. On Linux you won't be able to use your regular [IP address](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/576)

There is a previous discussion on the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666789/receiving-udp-broadcast-packets-on-linux?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

In order to Listen to Broadcast packets you need to use the following.

```
sock.bind(("<broadcast>", port_num))
or
sock.bind(("", port_num))
```